# When to use TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout vs. NetworkStream.ReadTimeout?

Tags: c#, tcp, stream, timeout, tcpclient

When programming a TCP server I would like to set the timeout period for reading the request from the client:

```
var tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
var networkStream = tcpListener.GetStream();

tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
networkStream.ReadTimeout = 10000;
```

See the last two lines. Which one should I prefer? Are they equal in terms of effectivity or in which way do they differ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Which one should I prefer?

Both the former and the latter will set their internal `Socket` to the received timeout. That same socket will bubble from from the `TcpClient` to the `NetworkStream` created, so I'd go with *the former*.

> Are they equal in terms of effectivity or in which way to they differ?

It's a good thing we can look at the [source code](http://sourceof.net).
This is [`TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,43d187d6cb48b739):

```
public int ReceiveTimeout 
{
    get 
    {
        return numericOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
                             SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout);
    }
    set 
    {
        Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
                          SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, value);
    }
}
```

Which sets the underling client socket's receive timeout (`Client` is of type `Socket`). And then passed to the `NetworkStream`:

```
public NetworkStream GetStream() 
{
    // Shortened for brevity
    if (m_DataStream==null)
    {
        m_DataStream = new NetworkStream(Client, true);
    }
    return m_DataStream;
}
```

And when the `NetworkStream` looks for the timeout, it looks inside the `Socket`:

```
public override int ReadTimeout 
{ 
    get 
    {
        int timeout = (int)m_StreamSocket.GetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
                                                          SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout);
        if (timeout == 0) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return timeout;
}
```